# regional Ju-Jutsu / Ju Jitsu / Jiu-Jiutsu organised Styles

Tags: jujutsu, style

Living in Germany, we have here a [German Ju-Jutsu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_ju-jutsu).
It was developed from masters of karate, judo etc. for police, justice staff etc. as a new martial art. Since then several new material had been added.
It is organised in regional and national associations with a unified curriculum and belt-tests.

So it is nothing a single person invented, just to be a grand master.

Are there in other countries similar martial art styles?
The search engines always give me hits to bjj or offshoots from bjj.

Comment: That sounds like what's sometimes referred to as a "hybrid" martial art, with many debates about whether it's a "proper" martial art. To name a few, Krav Maga, Systema, and Combatsu have been fairly forthright about how they're synthesized from other styles. Personally, I think that almost any good martial art draws influences and techniques from others since that's a method of learning.

Comment: I would call the 'German' Ju Jutsu a proper martial art.  
It has a defined set of techniques, quite a lot to choose from.  
Depending on your body and constitution the suitable techniques may vary.  

It has technique tests, randori, 'pressure' tests.
Light contact competitions are there also. Also demontrations if you prefer.

The competitions in karate seem to be rather no contact. You can get banned for hitting your opponent.

Comment: Kajukenbo, kudo, combat hapkido, and shidokan are some similar concepts that come to mind. These are all hybrid martial arts. And yes, anyone can start one and become the grandmaster 10th dan overnight. No need for any certification.

Comment: Incidentally, most "legit" martial arts usually started from one guy just declaring himself as grandmaster 10th dan. Go back far enough, and that is usually the case. That shouldn't matter too much. What you should look for is pedigree: who they trained with, how long, rank they achieved, etc. Even then, rank and time spent under someone is highly subjective. Jigoro Kano (founder of Judo) achieved menkyo at age 23. That's basically the highest you can go. Yet he only spent like 2 years on it, and 4 years with another school before that. But, look at what he accomplished!

Answer (score 1):

We have the Jitusu federation in the UK which is a bit the way you describe... But also a ton of other styles.  Martial arts has been a thing in the UK since 1905 or so so there are a ton of them here.

Oddly though police martial arts training has largely been phased out in the uk as I understand it.  The police judo club is long gone.  They learn a little of Tony Blauer's S.P.E.A.R. system but other than that there is very little mandatory martial arts training for the general police.  I believe the armed response teams get more training.

Comment: Oddly the Ju Jutsu here was developed for police, justice staff etc. Just as you described, also here the police uses now a minor training system.